# RSS/Atom feed provider/reader with "more entries" option?

Tags: rss, feeds, atom, rss-reader

I am quite sure the question title is not helpful, thus, here is the long version:

Is there any "common practice" method to extend feeds to give readers an option to load more entries?

What I want to achive is providing search results in a simple-to-browse way. I thought, feeds would be nice. However, neither RSS nor Atom provide a standard mechanism to get "more entries".

I know "CoolIris" uses `<atom:link rel="previous" ... />` and `<atom:link rel="next" ... />` in its media feeds to achive this ([reference](http://www.cooliris.com/developer/reference/media-rss/)), but using "previous" and "next" is not in the Atom specification. So this is also a very non-standard way.

Since I will create the feeds myself, I could use any method. However, is there **any** reader out there which will unterstand something like this?

Comment: Cooliris is using the [Media RSS](http://www.rssboard.org/media-rss "Media RSS") extension.

Comment: Yes, it does, but only for the content. For linking to the "next page" it uses "atom:link" in the non-standard way I described in my question. (Look at "Multipage Galleries" on the webpage I posted for reference.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you want correctly, you want to implement "paged search results" in a Atom/RSS feed.

I don't think this type of thing is widely implemented, but there is a proposed standard (via Amazon.com) at [OpenSearch.org](http://www.opensearch.org)—look specifically at the [OpenSearch response elements](http://www.opensearch.org/Specifications/OpenSearch/1.1#OpenSearch_response_elements).

Comment: This looks great. Although I don't want to implement searching, this is definitly the best direction for me to continue. - Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As to any existing reader which will understand this?

Probably not out of the box, but **Awasu** is easily extendable, and can understand Atom/RSS extension namespaces/elements via [Metadata Modules](http://www.awasu.com/help/3.0/hh_start.htm), look under the "Advanced Features" section of the help. I've even created a couple Metadata Modules to extract geographical and earthquake data embedded in feeds, and added them to Awasu's user Wiki: [Metadata modules on Awasu's Wiki](http://www.awasu.com/wiki/Extensions#Metadata_modules).

To my knowledge, Awasu is the only Atom/RSS reader that can easily capture, display *and* republish Atom/RSS extension namespaces/elements; really a shame for non-Awasu users, as there is a lot of additional extension namespaces/elements in feeds today.

Awasu is well supported; there is little it can't do, and help from the developer is rarely more than 24 hours away.

Comment: Awasu looks quite promissing. But since almost everyone else would not be able to use the provided data, I will look into the other answer first. Anyway - Thanks!